# Efficient way of doing numerical integration on a 2d array with variable integration length

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy, vectorization, cumsum

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019572/efficient-way-of-performing-integral-on-an-image) about numerically integrating on a 2d array with fixed length. Now what if the integration length is not fixed? For each cell as the starting point, I want to keep integrating until it encounters a cell with value of the opposite sign. So suppose in a column from bottom to top it is `[1,2,5,4,-2,-3,2]`, if I do the integral for the first element, it will integrate the first four elements (they are all positive). If I start from the fifth element, it will just integrate `-2` and `-3`. Are there any ways to vectorize it or speed it up instead of using a double for loop to first find the integration length for each cell and then do the integral?

Or a simplified problem is just to integrate the positive elements:
example:

```
data = [
-2, -1, 4, -2,-1;
1,  2,  3,  4, 5;
5, -4, -3,  2, 5;
3, -3, -9,  5, 7;
2, -2,  7, -5, 1;
2,  3,  1, -3, -3]

integrated_data = [
0,  0, 7,  0,  0;
13, 2, 3, 11, 18;
12, 0, 0   7, 13;
7,  0, 0,  5,  8;
4,  0, 8,  0,  1;
2,  3, 1,  0,  0]
```

Comment: please add an example e.g. a [5 , 5] matrix and the expected output.

Comment: Are you asking about Matlab or NumPy?

Comment: Why do you have a 0 in the upper left entry of integrated_data?  Shouldn't it be -2?

Comment: Your "integrated data" example looks like applying `np.maximum(array, 0)` and then using `cumsum`.

Answer (score 0):

A vectorization solution in MATLAB

```
data = [
-2, -1, 4, -2,-1;
1,  2,  3,  4, 5;
5, -4, -3,  2, 5;
3, -3, -9,  5, 7;
2, -2,  7, -5, 1;
2,  3,  1, -3, -3];
data1 = [-ones(1,size(data,2)) ;flipud(data)]
df = find([-1 ;diff((data1(:))>=0)] == 1)-1;
data1(data1<0) =0;
c1 = cumsum(data1(:));
data1(df) = data1(df) - [0 ;diff(c1(df))];
c2 = cumsum(data1(:));
c2(data1==0)=0;

c2=reshape(c2,size(data1));
result = flipud(c2(2:end,:))
```